# Is there a way to terminate a certain website with cmd? (Example www.youtube.com)

Tags: google-chrome, cmd.exe

So I remember you can terminate a website from the PID but you can't terminate with its Imagename?
cause you if you see in task manager all the names are just "Google Chrome" Not The name of the website

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`tasklist /M chrome* /FI "WindowTitle eq YouTube*"`

- `Tasklist` creates a list of currently running tasks.
- `/M`  Lists all tasks currently using the given exe/dll name.
- `/FI` Filters based on criteria
- `"WindowTitle eq YouTube*"` aka the title of the Window must start with the word YouTube.

Then you have the PID. You can use [PsKill](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pskill) to kill the process.

Comment: THanks for the answer

Comment: @Gasic https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers